# Any way to parse mysql query to extract select strings, join strings,where clause strings and so on

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, string, string-parsing

I have lots of query like the following. Is there any way to parse this query and extract sub queries and its select strings, join strings, where condition strings

```
 select count(1) count from (
        SELECT count(party.id) as count
        FROM party

        LEFT OUTER JOIN party_identifier on party.id = party_identifier.party_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN blood_type on blood_type.id = party.blood_type_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN education_level on education_level.id = party.education_level_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN religion on religion.id = party.religion_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN living_arrangement on living_arrangement.id = party.living_arrangement_id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN patient_patient_search patient_patient_search on patient_patient_search.patient_id = party.id



      WHERE  party.type = "Patient" AND party.record_status_id = 1 AND party_identifier.source_note = 'simplifyMD Patient ID'

       AND   (  patient_patient_search.patient_search_id in (1.0) ) and   ((1 and nullif(party.birth_date,'0000-00-00') is not null)) 
       AND   ((1 and party.ethnicity_id is not null))   
       AND   (  party.preferred_language_id is not null and  1 )   
       GRPOUP BY party.id) 
  as count
```

Output like

```
query[1] => {:select=>"count(1)",:from=>"party",
             :sub_query=>{:select=>"count(party.id)",:joins=>['party_identifier on party.id = party_identifier.party_id','blood_type on blood_type.id = party.blood_type_id',......],
             :where=>"party.type = "Patient" AND party.record_status_id = 1....."}
            }
```

Comment: Not easily - SQL can be a Turing-complete language in itself, this won't be an easy task. Why are you wanting to parse it anyway?

Comment: Using regex is not very save to parse SQL, but for most languages there should be libraries that can parser SQL, so you should tell for which programming language you need this.

Comment: I've reached maximum join limit in MySQL(i.e 61), so I thought if I'm able to parse I could write a program to reduce joins in some other way

Comment: @t.niese ruby would be nice, but I'm fine with  any language that can produce this output

Comment: You are looking for an SQL parser (probably using a grammar and a parser generator; regular expressions [are not up to that task](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19491739/1468366)). Others have asked about this before, so please check out [existing questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+parser).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anyone know of a Ruby SQL parser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488791/anyone-know-of-a-ruby-sql-parser)